# Combine RGB color values in JavaScript to form a blend

Tags: javascript, colors, rgba

So, in JavaScript, if I have a percentage of red and green right, say 35% red, 65% green, how can I combine them? I am not completely sure on the terminology of this, and it is possible that it is simpler than I think.
I see that on http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm
they have a value that ranges from 0-255. Is it easy to assign a value from 0-255 for both red and green to mix?
If it is not incredibly different, does adding alpha to the mix work too?

I want the color to be able show up in a canvas, but once I have the mixed value this should work fine. So I need a legitimate value that I can put into fillStyle.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.fillStyle="the blended color";
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RGB (Red, Green, Blue) have indeed values from 0-255 for each color.
So I assume that converting the percentage in a value within that range should work fine?

As you perform the following code for each color you can combine all values to get an RGB value.

```
color = (percentage / 100.00) * 255.00
```

**Example snippet**

```js
function percentageToRGB(r,g,b) {
    var r = parseInt((r/100)*255);
    var g = parseInt((g/100)*255);
    var b = parseInt((b/100)*255);
    
    return "rgb("+ r +","+ g +","+ b +")";
}

document.getElementById("block").style.background = percentageToRGB(35, 65, 0);
```

```css
#block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    Hello
</div>
```

Comment: But how would I turn this into a working value that can be interpreted as a color?

Comment: @Raven, a example is given now.

Comment: Great, this works for what I need and is very understandable.